# Joomla - Remove slider in featured article page.

Tags: php, joomla, slider, article

I've been struggling for a week trying to figure it out about my Joomla homepage.

the homepage includes slider and as my designer designed it to be featured article homepage so I had to coming up with featured article with the layout showing in my homepage

the homepage is

http://www.scottilicious.com/egat

homepage it looks fine but the problem I get is when I want to view each featured article, the slider and the featured services section are shown in the page which is wrong. 
I don't want that to show up so I went down to

```
/Components/Com_content/views/featured/tmpl/default.php
```

in order to see if I can do something there but there's no chance

I'm in misery right now being lost about this as I have to the website done within a week.
If you guys have any solution about this or any suggestions, I would appreciate a lot.

One more question, I would like to ask if it's possible for me to create separate featured article template.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Assuming this is a module, could you not simply assign the slider to the homepage only?

Comment: never edit `/components/com_content/views/featured/tmpl/default.php` it will destroy your site if your customer uses the update function in the admin panel. Instead copy `default.php` to `/templates/YOURTEMPLATE/html/com_content/featured/` and edit it there. It overwrites the default page and stays working after updates.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a module assign it in your modulemanagement to just show on "home".

If not: Check the alias to see on which page you are by using:

```
$currentMenuItem = JSite::getMenu()->getActive();
$alias = $currentMenuItem->alias;
if($alias == "home") 
    // show the slider
else
    stop(); // Hammertime
```

Good luck!